# Why am I getting a 400 bad request error? Using the Django Rest framework as a backend and React as a frontend for my web application

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch, bad-request

I am developing a simple web application that utilizes the openweathermap api. There is an api call to a view that returns the api data, and displays the temp & description for the weather of the particular city that the user types in.

The api call below is another call for a new feature that allows the user to save a particular weather data of their choosing. It takes the temp & desc from the state, and sends it to the backend view. The view then saves that data into the database, and returns a Response that I will then use to display the data in the same api call. It is giving me a 400 error. I console logged the temp & desc and they both print out correct so I am not sending undefined data to the backend. Could it be the way I am serializing the data?

**Front end api call**

```
const saveWeather = (temperature, description) => {
     const requestOptions = {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            temperature: temperature,
            description: description
          })
        };
    
    fetch("/api/savedweather", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log("OK");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**View**

```
class SaveWeather(APIView):
serializer_class = WeatherSerializer

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        temperature = serializer.data.get('temperature')
        description = serializer.data.get('description')
        weather = Weather(temperature=temperature, description=description)
        weather.save()
        return Response(WeatherSerializer(weather).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    return Response({'Bad Request': "Invalid Data..."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Model**

```
from django.db import models

class Weather(models.Model):
    temperature = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Serializer Class**

```
from .models import Weather
from rest_framework import serializers 

class WeatherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Weather
        fields = ('temperature', 'description')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to tell without knowing the model and serializer definitions.

but since it clearly seems to be serializaer validation error, you can check the errors thrown by serializaers with `serializer.errors` field.

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    ...
    return Response(WeatherSerializer(weather).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

print(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just added my model & serializer class above. I also used the serializer errors & it gave me this `{'temperature': [ErrorDetail(string='A valid integer is required.', code='invalid')]}`

Comment: As it says, temperature is not integer, check `request.data` if `temperature` in integer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the feedback i just changed temperature to a DecimalField.